# Pyspark : how do I apply the function to get slope in a dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe like this (x and y columns, each with 6 datapoints). I want to be able to extract the slope by fitting a simple regression line (basically to see the trend of y, increasing or decreasing).

```
+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|x                 |y                                                                                                                                       |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|[3.42102562348192E-6, 4.2159323917750995E-6, 3.924587540944015E-6, 4.167182871752131E-6, 4.109192066532302E-6, 4.297804458327455E-6]    |
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|[1.384402399630826E-5, 9.913141993957704E-6, 1.1145077060247102E-5, 1.1005472165326649E-5, 1.1004462921073546E-5, 1.1004462921073546E-5]|
+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to use this function but I am getting errors when applying to dataframe. what is the correct way to apply this function which takes in 2 arrays?

```
import numpy as np
def trendline(x,y, order=1):
    coeffs = np.polyfit(x, y, order)
    slope = coeffs[-2]
    return float(slope)

#example to run
x_example=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
y_example=[3.42102562348192,4.2159323917750995,3.924587540944015,4.167182871752131,4.109192066532302,4.297804458327455 ]
slope=trendline(x_example,y_example)
print(slope)
```

this functions works itself like the example above but i have trouble applying to the dataframe , i want to create a new column in the dataframe with returned slople.

thank you!!

I tried this and it didn't work

```
def get_slope_func(x,y, order=1):
    coeffs = np.polyfit(x, y, order)
    slope = coeffs[-2]
    return float(slope)
get_slope = pandas_udf(get_slope_func, returnType=LongType())

df.select(get_slope(col("x"), col("y"))).show()
```

Comment: You will have to pass the values by `x = df['x'].values` and `y = df['y'].values` where `df` is your dataframe. Then if I use `np.polyfit(x[0],y.T)` it works for me. Try it out?

Comment: @NikP I tried that and have error "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list"

Comment: btw my code is like this:
`df_pandas=df.toPandas()
x = df_pandas['x'].values
y = df_pandas['y'].values
np.polyfit(x[0],y.T,1) 
`
or `get_slope_func(x,y)`

Comment: On which line do you get this error "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list" ?

Comment: @NikP np.polyfit(x[0],y.T,1). same error for get_slope func line as well since it is just a function i wrote calling polyfit

Comment: what are the shapes and type of `x` and `y` in your `df_pandas`?

Comment: @nikP it is exactly like what i wrote in the post - just x and y 2 columns, both are arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are returning a **`float`** in **`get_slope_func`** and in registering your **`udf`** you have set return type as **`LongType()`** which is basically a **`BigInt`** in **`SQL`**. Set your **`returnType`** to **`DoubleType()`**.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.type import *
import numpy as np
def get_slope_func(x,y,order=1):
    coeffs = np.polyfit(x, y, order)
    slope = coeffs[-2]
    return float(slope)
get_slope = F.udf(get_slope_func, returnType=DoubleType())

df.select(get_slope(F.col("x"), F.col("y")).alias("slope")).show(truncate=False)
#+----------------------+
#|slope                 |
#+----------------------+
#|1.2303624369449727E-7 |
#|-3.1609849970704353E-7|
#+----------------------+
```

Comment: Getting this error 'PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'TypeError: expected 1D vector for x'', any idea why?